# Example of integral extension of degree $p$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, invariant-theory, integral-extensions

For a prime $p$, does there exist an example of a (pair of) domains (if yes any way to construct?) $R$ and $S$ such that

1. Both $R$ and $S$ are normal complete local domains
2. $S$ contains an alg. closed field of char 0.
3. $R\hookrightarrow S$ is an integral extension of degree $p$

and, if possible, I also would like to have:

4. $\mathbb{Z}_p$ acts on $S$ with $R=S^{\mathbb{Z}_p}$, the ring of invariants.

I was hoping to construct with something from $\mathbf{k}[[ X ]]$, but having no further thoughts.

Comment: Have you tried some obvious action of your cyclic group on the power series ring?

Comment: Yes, I tried that way as well, not able see the group action clearly, hence not able to compute the ring of invaiants. In fact what I think is once I can _construct_/obtain the ring of invariants, the **integral** extension part will be taken care of (not sure of the degree of the extn though)! So will be the **local**. Still the normality and completeness are remaining.

Comment: Any cyclic group of order $n$ acts by multiplying $X$ by the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of unity.